# Не рендерится элемент указанный в f:ajax composite component

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

Здравствуйте!

Есть такой компонент:

```
<h:body>
    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name="required" default="false"/>
        <composite:attribute name="showLabel" default="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name="placeholder" required="true"/>
        <composite:attribute name="label"/>
        <composite:attribute name="addonIcon"/>

        <composite:clientBehavior name="updateEvent" event="valueChange" targets="inputId"/>
        <composite:editableValueHolder name="input" targets="inputId"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
    <composite:implementation>
        <h:panelGroup id="inputPanel">
            <h:panelGroup
                    styleClass="full-width #{not empty facesContext.getMessageList(''.concat(cc.clientId).concat(':inputId')) ? 'form-group has-error' : 'form-group'}">
                <h:outputLabel for="inputId" value="#{not empty cc.attrs.label ? cc.attrs.label : cc.attrs.placeholder}"
                               rendered="#{cc.attrs.showLabel}"/>
                <span class="#{not empty cc.attrs.addonIcon ? 'input-group' : ''}" style="width: 100%;">
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.addonIcon}" class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa #{cc.attrs.addonIcon}" aria-hidden="true"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="inputId"
                             value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                             styleClass="full-width form-control"
                             p:placeholder="#{cc.attrs.placeholder}"
                             required="#{cc.attrs.required}"
                             label="#{not empty cc.attrs.label ? cc.attrs.label : cc.attrs.placeholder}">
                    <f:ajax execute="inputPanel" render="inputPanel" event="blur"/>
                </h:inputText>
            </span>
                <h:panelGroup
                        rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList(''.concat(cc.clientId).concat(':inputId'))}"
                        class="help-block">
                    <h:message for="inputId"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </composite:implementation>
</h:body>
```

И его вызов:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <util:inputText value="#{offerMap.totalSeats}"
                    required="true"
                    placeholder="Total Seats">
        <f:validateLongRange for="input" minimum="1" maximum="#{validator.offerMaxTotalSeats}"/>
        <f:ajax event="updateEvent" execute="@this" render=":seatsAvailable"
                listener="#{addOffer.seatsAvailableListener}"/>
    </util:inputText>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <util:inputText id="seatsAvailable"
                    value="#{offerMap.seatsAvailable}"
                    placeholder="Seats available">
        <f:validateLongRange for="input" minimum="1" maximum="#{offerMap.totalSeats - 1}"/>
    </util:inputText>
</div>
```

`Listener` вызывается и выполняется нормально. Но рендер не выполняется на втором элементе `seatsAvailable`. Если я ставлю `render="@form"`, тогда обновляется, но так как у меня в форме есть скрипт, который перематывает на верх, то этот способ не подойдет. Я так же пробовал помещать код вызова в `h:panelGroup` и рендерить `render=":block:seatsAvailable"`, но ничего не происходило.

Помогите с решением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете retargetAttachedObject механизм, суть которого заключается в простом присваивании ajax события к компоненту. Ваш вопрос как раз про самый существенный недостаток этого способа: выполнение события в контексте целевого компонента. Иными словами компоненты для передачи на сервер и обновления ищутся относительно `<h:inputText id="inputId"` в пространстве id составного компонента, а `seatsAvailable` находится на уровень выше.

Для устранения этого недостатка нужно использовать абсолютную адресацию, она начинается с `:` и содержит id всех контейнеров до целевого компонента. На странице в примере bobzer'а это будет `render=":myForm:seatsAvailable"`, в составном компоненте можно получить клиентский id данного компонента `render=":#{cc.clientId}:seatsAvailable"`.

Comment: Спасибо. Но я решил сделать через js, потому что ajax'у нужно время на получение ответа от сервера, что может привести пользователя в замешательство.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать в атрибуте `render` полный идентификатор поля ввода, а не компонента, с указанием идентификатора формы. Примерно так:

```
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <util:inputText value="#{offerMap.totalSeats}"
                            required="true"
                            placeholder="Total Seats">
                <f:validateLongRange for="input" minimum="1" maximum="#{10000}"/>
                <f:ajax event="updateEvent" execute="@this" render="myForm:seatsAvailable:inputId"
                        listener="#{offerMap.seatsAvailableListener}"/>
            </util:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <util:inputText id="seatsAvailable"
                            value="#{offerMap.seatsAvailable}"
                            placeholder="Seats available">
                <f:validateLongRange for="input" minimum="1" maximum="#{10000}"/>
            </util:inputText>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

При указании `render="myForm:seatsAvailable:inputId"` поле ввода для `seatsAvailable` обновляется при изменении значения в `totalSeats`. Весь код вашей страницы не приведён, там могут быть промежуточные контейнеры между `h:form` и компонентом, поэтому на всякий случай посмотрите в отладчике браузера какой идентификатор у поля ввода в HTML-коде страницы.

Comment: мне кажется немного неправильным использование на странице данных уровня составного компонента, ведь проектировщику страницы достаточно знать лишь интерфейс составного компонента, а не его внутренности...